# Hide get Mobile App SharePoint 2019 on prem

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019

Trying to hide get mobile app button on communication site 2019 on prem - I see various ways to do this in SPO but any ideas for 2019 on prem?

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOTB solution to hide the button for SharePoint Server 2019.

If you are open for custom solution, you can hide the button using CSS hosted by [SPFx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2019-support).

Reference: [Remove Feedback Buttons from SharePoint Footer through Application Customizer.](https://n8d.at/remove-feedback-buttons-from-sharepoint-footer-through-application-customizer/)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the file below for SharePoint 2019 (on prem)

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\Next\spclient\24.sp-pages-mobileupsellview.js
```

Near the end of the file, update the "display" parameter to "none !important;"

```
display:none !important;
```